# PHP - Sort keys of an array that are different strings but contain numbers at the end

Tags: php, arrays, string, sorting, numerical

I have the following keys in my array:

```
Array (  
    "Danger - 69" => Array();  
    "Fab - 67" => Array();  
    "Cat - 68" => Array();  
)
```

I want it to be ordered by the number in the string and not the first letter in the string itself, like this:

```
Array (  
    "Fab - 67" => Array();  
    "Cat - 68" => Array();  
    "Danger - 69" => Array();  
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
<?php

$data = array (
"Danger - 69" => Array(),
"Fab - 67" => Array(),
"Cat - 68" => Array(),
);


uksort($data, function($a, $b) {
   $pos = strrpos($a, '-');
   if ($pos !== false) {
      $a = (int) trim(substr($a,$pos+1));
   }
   $pos = strrpos($b, '-');
   if ($pos !== false) {
      $b = (int) trim(substr($b,$pos+1));
   }

   return $a - $b;

}); 

var_dump($data);
```